# Failed to get the sites followed by user from Microsoft Graph

Tags: authentication, microsoft-graph-api, sites

I am trying to retrieve the sites that the user is following from Microsoft Graph Explorer.

I found this document to do that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/sites-list-followed?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

In that document, they mentioned that a Bearer token is required for Authorization. But where can I get that token?

If I try to query without a token, I am getting "Authentication failed, No valid token found" 401 error. How to resolve that error?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using **Graph Explorer**, which is a Microsoft-created user interface to access the **Graph API**, you don't need to specify the token in the headers. When you sign into [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) with your user account, you'll automatically obtain a token, and it will be automatically supplied in your request.

You can actually retrieve the token of the signed-in user from [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) as well, by clicking on the **Access token** button.

[image]

If you're accessing the **Graph API** from any other interface (e.g. code), you'll need to manually form the request headers and include the token that you've obtained.

How to obtain a token for a service application would require further information, you can read more from the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts#access-tokens)

Here is a simple example using Python and MSAL, as well as the constructed request header.

```
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id         = client_id,
    client_credential = client_secret,
    authority         = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}")

scopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]

token = None
token = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes = scopes)

req_headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token['access_token']
    }
```